# Managing timezones for different users

Tags: timezone

I have a website where I have many users coming from different countries. Users can  schedule a task based on their timezone. Now there is a cron running on the server after every min, the cron executes a script which checks if there are any scheduled task of any user and if so it does the needful.

Since my server is based in the US, the script executed by the cron considers the timezone of the US. What do I have to do in my script that will execute the user's task based on user's timezone instead of server's timezone?

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: language?  would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Lookup the user's timezone.
2. Compute the current time in the user's timezone.
3. For each job, look up the last time it was run and compute the next time it should run.
4. For any job whose next run time is now or in the past, run that job and update the record of the last time each job was run.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on the iPhone a few months ago.

My solution was to capture the time as a string. So if the user selected 8am, I would just capture 08:00 and their time zone e.g. Europe/London.

Every 5 minutes or so on my server, I could then convert this 08:00 into the current UTC time based on the timezone. If this time was "present", I would carry about a check on the user's transport status and issue alerts.

To help me with the TimeZones, I used NodaTime. http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/